# Match a line with no space

Tags: grep

How do I match a line with no space in grep? For example,

```
xyz
a b c
d e f
```

Only xyz should match. The pattern `^\S*$` does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
$ grep '^\S*$' input
xyz
```

**OR**

```
$ grep '^[^ ]*$' input
xyz
```

Comment: Works, not sure how I could not get it with my regex. Thanks.